# Adding a Office 365 shared mailbox account for email-to-activity processing via IMAP

Tags: email

We have a shared mailbox in Office/Microsoft365 that we want to add to Civi as an "Email Account" for "email-to-activity processing" via IMAP.

A shared mailbox does not have its own license/username.

So, in this case, the username and password are for the authorised user, but the [mailbox name needs to be specified as the shared mailbox](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/imap-settings-shared-mailbox-office-exchange-online.html). Otherwise the authorised user's mailbox will be accessed.

Civi only allows you to specify the username (assumes that the mailbox name and the username are the same), so how to specify which mailbox to check?

Comment: if i were to add a tag that covers all office/microsoft type question, what would make most sense in terms of the tag? 'microsoft' or 'microsoft-office' etc?

Comment: 'microsoft-office', I guess?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I have the same problem. (and don't have yet enough reputation points to add a comment, so using this answer field instead...)